# Is there a way to mock "import .." in python unittest?

Tags: python-unittest, mox

I know in python by using mox, we can emulate the behaviour of a class propery or method.
But when we new a instance or a target class, it does many things in its "import ..." class.
My question is how to simulate the "import .." class behavour in mox? 
in client.py

```
from my.test import hander
......
```

in hander.py:

```
def _doLotOfThings():
#do a lot of things
_doLotOfThings()
```

Is there a way to inject hander.py's _doLotOfThings() before import hander that let it does nothing?

Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to move the do lots of things, and only do them `if __name__ == '__main__'`?

Comment: @doctorlove I mean the do lots of things is in the method I need to test, I cannot modify the sourcecode but only test code. I want to mock this method before `import hander` from testsuite